# Set specific time in specific timezone using momentjs

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am making a web-app and my users need to select a specific time in a specific time zone.  For example, selecting *8th November 2013 at noon in New York City*.  Unfortunately, I cannot properly set the date in the momentjs object.

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/didier_/myHq3/1/) that reproduces my problem.  What am I doing wrong?

```
var data = {date: 8, hour: 12, minute: 0, month: 10, year: 2013}
var ret = moment({}).tz("America/New_York");
_.each(data, function(val,key){
   ret.set(key, val);
});
$("h1").text("the date should be the 8 th but it is the "+ ret.utc().get("date")) // 7
```

many thanks,

didier

Answer (score 0):

Your script is a bit convoluted, but it does seem to *work* in the fiddle.  At least, I don't get an error in Google Chrome.  Other browsers may vary.

However, it's not going to always produce the correct results.  When you initialize it, you are setting a moment as of "now" in New York.  But then you replace the values one property at a time.  This doesn't take into account that "now" might not have the same offset as the date you are feeding it due to daylight saving time fluctuations.

Moment-timezone doesn't currently have functionality to create a moment *from* a time in a particular zone.   This has been requested in [issue #11](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/issues/11), and there is a pull-request that has been merged in [#25](https://github.com/moment/moment-timezone/pull/25), but has not yet been released.  If you want to work with the development version from the sources, you can try it out now, such as follows:

```
var m = moment.tz("2013-10-08T12:00:00","America/New_York");
```