# Keeping the time fields but changing the timezone with moment.js

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs

I have a moment object to which I need to apply a timezone, but without altering the values of the hour or minute field.  For example, if my moment contains the date '2013-10-10T15:00:00+00:00' I want to be able to change the zone to 'America/Los_Angeles' so that when I print the moment I obtain '2013-10-10T15:00:00-07:00'

(for those of you familiar with Joda I'm after the `withZoneRetainFields()` functionality)

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x8JQW/5/) with the basic setup, showing the problem.  How can I alter the last item so that it gives the desired output?

Comment: I'm not sure why you would want it to move from 15:00 to 16:00.  Is that a typo?  If you are just looking for a way to construct a time that's already in that time zone, see my answer to a similar question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19735888/634824)

Comment: Apologies for the mistake, yes it should be 15:00 not 16:00.  I've updated the question, and also updated the fiddle to provide a potential solution.  Given that the change you mention is not yet released would you recommend this as the best way to do it in the meantime?

Answer (score 3):

I recommend looking into the moment-timezone.js library for managing timezones. It offers an interesting `.zone()` function for manipulating timezones on a moment date object.

I've included a link to the relevent issue on moment.js's GitHub issues:

[Switching timezone of moment without changing the values](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/849)

Note, though I don't recommend it, you can also manually adjust a date for the desired timezone. In the below example, I'm creating a date in the **client's** timezone, changing the timezone on the date object to UTC, then fixing the value of the date such that the hours and minutes retain the same value.

```
// Takes a moment.js date object, and converts
// it to UTC timezone, while maintaining the 
// selected hour/mins of the input date.
function convertDateToUTC (date){

    // Current timezone's offset. Minutes offset from UTC
    var offset = date.utcOffset();

    // Convert selected date to UTC
    date = date.utc();

    // Adjust the time to.
    date.add(offset, "minutes");

    return date;
};
```